# Unable to import numpy on Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, spyder, macos-big-sur

I'm using Python 3.10.2 through Spyder on macOS Bigsur (M1). I have installed numpy 1.22.4 and able to import it through the terminal but not through Spyder.
Below is the error I get on Spyder when I import it:

```
Original error was: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-310-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I've already tried uninstalling numpy and reinstalling through pip3 and adding the Python directory as the env variable, but nothing helped so far.

How do I import it on Spyder?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) How did you install Spyder?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba - Standalone installer for MacOS: https://www.spyder-ide.org/

Comment: And did you follow [the steps](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/5/faq.html#using-packages-installer) to connect Spyder to your system Python?